# Isoperimetric inequality via Lagrange multipliers in infinite dimensions. End of a proof.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

Let $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be an injective $C^2$ curve with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(2\pi)$ and velocity $1$ (parametrized by the arc length). Write it as $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$. We know that its length is given by
$$ l(\gamma)=\int_0^{2\pi} \| \dot{\gamma}(t)\|dt=2\pi$$
and the area inside it is given, by Green's formula, by
$$ A(\gamma)=\int_0^{2\pi} x(t)\dot{y}(t)dt.$$
Thus, the isoperimetric problem can be seen as finding 
$$ \max_{l(\gamma)=2\pi} A(\gamma). $$
Using Lagrange multpliers, one gets that there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \dot{y}=\lambda\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\dot{x}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}}\right),\quad -\dot{x}=\lambda\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\dot{y}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}}\right).$$
Using $\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}=1$ and integrating in time, 
$$ y=\lambda \dot{x}+C,\quad -x=\lambda\dot{y}+D.$$
Solving this, one derives
$$ x(t)=-D+\alpha\cos(t/\lambda)+\beta\sin(t/\lambda),\quad y(t)=C+\delta\cos(t/\lambda)+\eta\sin(t/\lambda),\quad t\in [0,2\pi].$$
I would like to obtain that $\gamma$ is a circle. I tried by setting some assumptions: $y(0)=y(2\pi)=0$ (by translating $\gamma$) and $y(\pi)=0$ (by rotating $\gamma$).

Comment: @jkabrg I have $\dot{y}=\lambda (\dot{x})^{\cdot}$, so $y=\lambda \dot{x}+C$. Look at the dot outside the parenthesis (up right).

Comment: That's not as readable as $d \over dt$

Comment: @jkabrg You're right. I edited the question.

Comment: Unrelated to your final problem, you need to be a bit more careful with the arc-length parametrisation. The condition that $|\dot{\gamma}|=1$ for all $t$ is not invariant under all variations and will cause problems in deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation. In this case, it is better to first consider all curves $\gamma$ and then reparametrise afterwards. This will of course lead to the same result.

Comment: @mlk Thank you for your comment. While I was writing the question, I had problems concerning what you mention. So, if I understand your point, we want to maximize $A(\gamma)$ among all curves $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $l(\gamma)=2\pi$ (not necessarily parametrized by the arc length). We assume that we have such a $\gamma$, and by Lagrange multipliers, $\dot{y}=\lambda\, d/dt (\dot{x}/\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2})$ and $-\dot{x}=\lambda\, d/dt (\dot{y}/\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2})$. ...

Comment: @mlk ... Now we parametrize by the arc length and derive $\dot{y}=\lambda \ddot{x}$ and $-\dot{x}=\lambda \ddot{y}$. I have a question: in my post, the domain of the curves $\gamma$ considered has to coincide with the length $l$? I mean, given any $l>0$, does it make sense to maximize $A(\gamma)$ among all curves $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $l(\gamma)=l$? Should the domain $[0,2\pi]$ be changed to $[0,l]$? I ask this because when we parametrize by the arc length, the domain changes from $[0,2\pi]$ to $[0,l]$ and I don't know if this may cause any problem.

Comment: @user39756 This corrected version is fine. Concerning your second question, it does not really matter. In this case the length is $2\pi$ anyway, but even if this is not the you can still parametrise uniformly (some authors might still call this arc-length), just then you will get $|\dot{\gamma}| = \frac{l}{2\pi}$ instead. This will add some constants to your equation, which will mostly cancel out, or in this case will give you a circle of different radius, which is the expected solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x,y)$ traces a circle centered at $(-D,C)$ with radius $\lambda$:

From $$y = \lambda \dot{x} + c\text{ and}\\-x=\lambda \dot{y} + D $$
follows
$$(D + x)^2 + (y - C)^2 = \lambda^2\left(\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2\right) = \lambda^2$$